# How to generate JavaScript file from Java Properties with Maven in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, maven, m2e

In an old Java web application there are many keys in properties files for internationalization. JavaScript functions also use this key to show some messages.

Actually this file is inline in HTML, dynamicly generated on JSPs, causing an increase of approximately 400 KB on each page request.
To improve performance slightly I generated JavaScript files with key|value with content like this:

```javascript
var b = {
    keys: {
        "key.one": "value.one",
        "key.two": "value.two"
    }
};
```

The JavaScript file path look like this:

[image: JavaScript files]

The message properties files are in the directory like this:

[image: Message properties files]

I need to read the message property files in the build to create the JavaScript files.
To do this, I am using [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/), set up this way:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>
            <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</argument>
        </arguments>
        <mainClass>com.brunocesar.build.GenerateI18NJSFiles</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

`GenerateI18NJSFiles` reads the properties files and generates the JavaScript files, but only when running maven build (e.g.: `mvn clean compile war:exploded`).
I need to generate them also in Eclipse.
SO, I set up the Eclipse `lifecycle-mapping` plugin like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <versionRange>[${exec-maven-plugin.version},)</versionRange>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                        <execute>
                            <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                        </execute>
                    </action>
                </pluginExecution>
            </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But it still is not generating the files in the Eclipse build, but only by Maven.

Is there is a way to set up Eclipse (maybe in `m2e-wtp`, maybe using another plugin) to generate the files and deploy in a container (such as JBoss, Tomcat, etc.)?

Comment: Do you execute the same goals in eclipse as on command line?

Comment: @Nachtgold Yeah, the same goals.

Comment: Try the goal *help:effective-pom* in eclipse and on command line. Maybe there is a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nachtgold, but the problem is not in `pom.xml` file, but in how `m2e-wtp` executes plugin lifecycle. As you can see in the question, works fine in command line.

Comment: Did you try a custom builder for your project? When m2e-wtp is not a good solution, maybe a handmade one could help you ... http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-94_run_pj.htm